# Twisted deferred chaining

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I have an application that manages modules calls asynchronously:

- it requests a deferred that triggers itself
- appends custom callback
- checks the returned code to see if = **CONTINUE**, otherwise handle errors

This is the code that returns a deferred to the main application:

```
def xxfi_connect(self, hostname):
    d = defer.Deferred()
    d.callback(Milter.ReturnCodes.CONTINUE)
    return d
```

To asynchronously append some code, I need to hook up my function call in the deferred function like this:

```
d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(self.run_mods, application.L_CONNECT)
d.callback(Milter.ReturnCodes.CONTINUE)
```

The trouble is that every function hooked up receive an argument containing the callback parameter (application.L_CONNECT).

Is it possible to achieve this without transporting the returncode in every function call ?

Ideally, I'd like my callback function to be like this:

```
def run_mods(self, level):
    pass
```

instead of

```
def run_mods(self, code, level):
    pass
```

because the `code` (Milter.ReturnCodes.CONTINUE) is only needed at the end of the chain

Answer (score 0):

distinguishing Successful or Erred `Deferred()`s is already a feature built into them.

```
>>> from twisted.internet import defer
>>> d = defer.Deferred()
>>> def errors(*args): raise Exception("i'm a bad function")
>>> def sad(*arg): print "this is not so good", arg
>>> def happy(*arg): print "this is good", arg
>>> d.addCallback(errors)
<Deferred at 0x106821f38>
>>> d.addCallbacks(happy, sad)
<Deferred at 0x106821f38>
>>> d.callback("hope")
this is not so good (<twisted.python.failure.Failure <type 'exceptions.Exception'>>,)
```

Any given "stage" in a chain of callbacks can easily know if it's following an error state, either by how it was added, as the argument to `addErrback()`, or the second argument to `addCallbacks()`, or by virtue of it's argument being an instance of `Failure()`

For more about deferred chaining see:  https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/defer.html

Comment: thank you, this is indeed something I can do, but what if, more generally, I chain 2 deferred and don't want the result from the top one sent to the child one ? Is this possible ?

Comment: you could interpose a callback function to discard some arguments, ie: `d.addCallback(lambda a, b: b)`